# Blank data from GET call in python requests when adding in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests, get

I'm using a GET request which runs successfully and provides me necessary details.

I'm trying to use parts of this resultant data from the GET call in an existing pandas dataframe by adding new columns.

Problem is I'm able to get the response data, but the dataframe is filled with just blank values.

However I'm able to see the data populated in my dataframe when I'm debugging the code

```
For index in range(Len(df)):
     Some API calls
     df.loc[index,"column"]= resultant_json["data_of_interest"]
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

In the above code, if I'm debugging, the values from the API calls are populated in the dataframe. If I'm executing my code dataframe is not filled.

P.S: my code is restricted for sharing. Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: how can users help you if you have not provided the code or the data ?

Comment: @D.L I sorted out my issue. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

In of the API calls, I was using a response data as a parameter for another GET request which wasn't getting set because of the shorter execution time.

So used
`time.sleep(3)`
before the GET request.